# Can I still using gradle plugin 2.30 in next year 2019?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Now my application using

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
```

After compiling I got message

> Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018

If I don't want to upgrade `gradle plugins` to `3.x` up.

Can I still use `gradle plugin` `2.30` in next year 2019?

Comment: Why you don't want to upgrade? any specific reason?

Comment: The more you fall back from current versions the more difficult it will become to maintain your software. This is a battle you will loose eventually.

Comment: You can keep using it just fine. But if you decide to upgrade to the newest version somewhere in 2019 you will find out that lots of features won't work and have been removed. Therefore you need to do a huge amount of refactoring to get your project to work with 3.x or maybe even 4.x.

My advice is to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why we have latest version in programming tools, and that is for better performance. You need to always update plugins and other necessary tools in other to have a fast working environment. You can read more about gradle plugin from this ref: `https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin`